# List index out of range (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, listiterator

I feel like I am constantly having this problem when I am writing a program, what I want to do is iterate over every value in my nested list and say that if it's not a zero, make it one.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryry3\Desktop\Python Projects\Games\Pygame Experiment\Sprint2.py", line 65, in <module>
    resetBoard()
  File "C:\Users\ryry3\Desktop\Python Projects\Games\Pygame Experiment\Sprint2.py", line 49, in resetBoard
    if board[i][j] != 0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my full code:

```
import random

grid = [100,100]
board = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0], 
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]


playerX = None
playerY = None
randX = 0
randY = 0

def getRandomGridPos():
    global randX, randY

    randX = int(random.uniform(0, grid[0]))     
    randY = int(random.uniform(0, grid[1]))

def main():
    pass

def printBoard():
    print str(board[0]).replace(',', '')
    print str(board[1]).replace(',', '')
    print str(board[2]).replace(',', '')
    print str(board[3]).replace(',', '')
    print str(board[4]).replace(',', '')
    print str(board[5]).replace(',', '')
    print str(board[6]).replace(',', '')
    print str(board[7]).replace(',', '')
    print str(board[8]).replace(',', '')
    print str(board[9]).replace(',', '')



def resetBoard():
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while i < 10:
        if board[i][j] != 0:
            board[i][j] = 0
            j += 1
            print "Looping"
        if j == 10:
            j = 0
            i += 1
            print "J == 10"
        if i == 10:
            j = 0
            i = 0
            print "I == 10" 
        else:
            j += 1


resetBoard()
```

Can someone help me find a solution and also help me not get this error anymore (explain why it happens)?

Comment: You're incrementing j in the first and last conditional.  Print I and j at the top of the while loop and watch what happens.

Comment: @BrianPendleton I am printing them and I see that j goes up as expected but the loop still goes on forever. Any ideas?

Comment: That means `i` isn't being incremented correctly.  Why not just loop using for statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE:

Sorry but I also encoutered another problem, my bad for not checking the code:
The final code should be:

```
while i < 10:
        if j == 10:
            j = 0
            i += 1
            print ("J == 10")
        elif board[i][j] != 0:
            board[i][j] = 0
            j += 1
            print ("Looping")
        else:
            j += 1
```

The problem I missed was that you should have checked the `j` boundary before trying to access the array, only then you should start the loop again.

---

The problem is in this part:

```
if j == 10:
            j = 0
            i += 1
            print "J == 10"
if i == 10:
            j = 0
            i = 0
```

if `i = 9, j= 10` then we enter into the first `if` which changes `i,j` to be 10,10
Then the code continues and we enter the second `if`, thus reseting `i` and `j` making the loop go again and again...
Solve it by deleting the second `if` part, since the `while` condition will make sure we will never go to that case in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much! I also had to change the J from 10 to 9 but you helped me solve it so much quicker. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You've already gotten several pointers to the cause of your error, but I just wanted to point out a clearer pattern to iterate multi-dimensional arrays:

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    for y in range(0, 10):

      # you will now have all values for a 10x10 array in x & y
      if board[x][y] != 0:
          board[x][y] = 0
```

If you really just want to make sure all board fields (10 x 10) are zeros, the following is even more consice:

```
# zero out a 10 x 10 multi-dimensional array
board = [[0] * 10] * 10
```

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely keep these in mind next time I do this!

Answer (score 1):

Your for reset board doesn't work for the following reasons:

- "if i == 10" ,i never actually reaches 10, since it is in a while loop which states "while i < 10". The loop would exit before i actually reaches 10
- no nested while loop. You need two while loops to reset the board.
- When j reaches 10 this line raises an index error: `if board[i][j] != 0:` , because j equals 10, and the maximum index you can take of a 10 element list is 9(since index starts at 0)

I recommend reading the following
http://introtopython.org/lists_tuples.html

I would add that one of the best ways to achieve what you want in python with loops is:

```
for row in board: # runs the following once for every item in board
    for item in row: # runs the following for every item in row. 
                     # A second for statement is required because 
                     # multidimensional lists are lists of lists.
        if(item != 0) 
            item = 0 #sets items to 0 if the item isn't equal to 0
```